# magento2 remote catecory_id when create new

Tags: magento2.3

When i create new category it have (ID:2). And when i load in frontend have it. How can i remote or hidden it?

```
<?php


namespace Mageplaza\Blog\Block\Category;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Mageplaza\Blog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface;
use Mageplaza\Blog\Helper\Data as HelperData;
use Mageplaza\Blog\Model\Category;
use Mageplaza\Blog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Mageplaza\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection;
use Mageplaza\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;


class Menu extends Template
{
/**
 * @var CollectionFactory
 */
protected $categoryCollection;

/**
 * @var CategoryFactory
 */
protected $category;

/**
 * @var HelperData
 */
protected $helper;

/**
 * Menu constructor.
 *
 * @param Context $context
 * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 * @param CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
 * @param HelperData $helperData
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    HelperData $helperData,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->categoryCollection = $collectionFactory;
    $this->category           = $categoryFactory;
    $this->helper             = $helperData;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * @param $id
 *
 * @return CategoryInterface[]
 */
public function getChildCategory($id)
{
    return $this->categoryCollection->create()->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $id)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('enabled', '1')->getItems();
}

/**
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getCollections()
{
    return $this->categoryCollection->create()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('level', '1')->addAttributeToFilter('enabled', '1');
}

/**
 * @param Category $parentCategory
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMenuHtml($parentCategory)
{
    $categoryUrl = $this->helper->getBlogUrl('category/' . $parentCategory->getUrlKey());
    $html        = '<li class="level' . $parentCategory->getLevel()
        . ' category-item ui-menu-item" role="presentation">'
        . '<a href="' . $categoryUrl . '" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">'
        . '<span>' . $parentCategory->getName() . '</span></a>';

    $childCategorys = $this->getChildCategory($parentCategory->getId());

    if (count($childCategorys) > 0) {
        $html .= '<ul class="level' . $parentCategory->getLevel() . ' submenu ui-menu ui-widget'
            . ' ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"'
            . ' role="menu" aria-expanded="false" style="display: none; top: 47px; left: -0.15625px;"'
            . ' aria-hidden="true">';

        /** @var Category $childCategory */
        foreach ($childCategorys as $childCategory) {
            $html .= $this->getMenuHtml($childCategory);
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }
    $html .= '</li>';

    return $html;
}

/**
 * @param Category $parentCategory
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPortoMenuHtml($parentCategory)
{
    $categoryUrl = $this->helper->getBlogUrl('category/' . $parentCategory->getUrlKey());
    $html        = '<li class="ui-menu-item level' . $parentCategory->getLevel() . ' parent" role="presentation">'
        . '<div class="open-children-toggle"></div>'
        . '<a href="' . $categoryUrl . '" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">'
        . '<span>' . $parentCategory->getName() . '</span></a>';

    $childCategories = $this->getChildCategory($parentCategory->getId());

    if (count($childCategories) > 0) {
        $html .= '<ul class="subchildmenu level' . $parentCategory->getLevel() . ''
            . ' ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"'
            . ' role="menu" aria-expanded="false"'
            . ' aria-hidden="true">';

        /** @var Category $childCategory */
        foreach ($childCategories as $childCategory) {
            $html .= $this->getMenuHtml($childCategory);
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }
    $html .= '</li>';

    return $html;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getBlogHomePageTitle()
{
    return $this->helper->getBlogConfig('general/name') ?: __('Blog');
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getBlogHomeUrl()
{
    return $this->helper->getBlogUrl('');
}
```

}

[image]

Please help me!

Comment: Just make sure I got it right, you want to hide a specific category from the frontend menu is that it?

Comment: no i want to hide the (ID:..)
Ex: Diete e Fitness (ID:2) to Diete e Fitness